what's the difference here between What is that? and What is this? — 2 questions
A guy points at the food of his friend. Is there a difference in meaning if he would have said "what is this"?
https://youtu.be/KkaJH1FlnTY?list=PLzhVds4scMG60ZZ4oq5EoiHmZQwHqEwFn&t=2978
A person at Hinative answered this question with

'This' is used for things that are nearer.
'What is this' is used to ask about something that is nearer to you.
'That' is used for things that are farther.
'What is that' is used to ask about something that is farther away
from you.

but he seems to be super off. What was the reason he claimed that?

The 'person at Hinative' is perfectly correct. The speaker asked "What's that?" because the food was in front of his friend and not of himself.

"this" and "that" are deictic, that is, expressing the speaker's sense of and attitude toward their surroundings. You could be standing facing me and only a foot away, holding something in your hand, and I could ask you "What's that?" as I look down at your hand. It is with you, not with me.  Or I could have something in my hand and open my palm to show you and ask you "Do you know what this is?" I could hold it between my fingers and dangle it right in front of your nose and ask you "Do you know what this is?"  I have it, you don't have it.
In the video clip the person who asks "What's that?" is referring to the item on the plate that was set down in front of another person. It is theirs.
And the "distance" can be measured in emotional units, so to speak, not centimeters. For example, if I order a green salad and the waiter puts a plate down in front of me with a burger on it, I might say "I didn't order that" signaling "I want this to be taken away from me".  There's an "emotional distance" between me and the burger. I didn't want a burger.

what would it mean if a person in video said "what is this"?

@Hey  Are you asking what it would mean if the person in that video had asked "What is this?"   It wouldn't make clear sense, given the context in the video.

so, saying "this" there would be a kind of a big mistake? I didn't know it's that big of a problem. would there a possibilty then that the other person asked him "what do you mean?". to signal that the question is that unclear?

@Hey   Given the physical setting, the restaurant context, and the actual underlying thing the speaker wants to know, "What is this?" would not sound idiomatic to me. Setting the speaker's accent aside, it might even identify the speaker as a non-native speaker.  There's an incongruity.  The speaker wants to know what it is that another member of the party has on a plate in front of him, and that other person is seated catty-corner from him at an oblong table, not directly opposite him.  It is a situation where the speaker, barring some unusual circumstance, would normally ask "What's that?"
